# Page Losing current position when click bootstrap collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap collapse in my project . Collapse is working fine but the problem is, I placed this collapsed menu after a long scroll ,

When I click the collapsible link, The page is scrolled to top.

How can I resolve this scroll issue, as I want the page at the same position as it was before collapse in.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <br />
    <h4><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div_addtraining">Insert Training</a><br /></h4>
    <div id="div_addtraining" class="collapse"  style="overflow-x:auto;">
      Test    Test    Test    Test    <br />Test    Test    Test    <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/sayunibobu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can't see the problem: http://jsbin.com/cefase/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @MoshFeu there is no scroll in your demo.

Comment: just check it http://jsbin.com/sayunibobu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @TJ I've added the link

Comment: @MoshFeu i added some scroll now you can test it

Comment: try removing the `#` from `href`

Comment: @AlinaAnjum I answered you. Take a look.

Comment: ok @MoshFeu i going to it

Comment: No @TJ I can't do this

Comment: @AlinaAnjum hmm.. why not? You can control the cursor style via CSS. What's the use of `href="#"` except for triggering the unwanted scroll..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `href` attribute. In case you are use `a` for the trigger just use the href for the id of the collapsed div (`#div_addtraining`).

**In bottom line:**

Replace

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div_addtraining">
```

to

```
<a href="#div_addtraining" data-toggle="collapse">
```

And working example:

```css
.row {
  margin-top:3000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <br />
    <h4><a href="#div_addtraining" data-toggle="collapse">Insert Training</a><br /></h4>
    <div id="div_addtraining" class="collapse"  style="overflow-x:auto;">
      Test    Test    Test    Test    <br />Test    Test    Test    <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I can't use margin-top trick because the page is fully responsive , it will create issu in future if I add some data to the top or before the collapse menu

Comment: and what did you changed in href, there is no change in your code except margin

Comment: It doesn't matter. The `margin-top` it's just to simulate the scrollable page. The point is the `href` attribute. Just replace it and let me know if it's working for you.

Comment: replace with what ? there is no change in your code

Comment: Sorry, it didn't paste well. the change was in the snippet. Now I replace it in the answer itself.

Comment: I need your support for this question :) I'll also support your answer

Comment: I glad to hear :) `I need your support for this question` What do you mean?